# Echo is not printing the correct value for a variable

Tags: shell, variable, echo

I have a variable in my shell script which is not getting resolved properly at run time:

Input

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVER_ERL_ARGS="+K true +A30 +P 1048576 \
     -kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}]"
echo ${SERVER_ERL_ARGS}
```

Output:

```
+K true +A30 +P 1048576 -kernel inet_default_connect_options a
```

Any reason behind this kind of behavior and how can I correct it.

Answer (score 15):

You have not quoted the variable expansion in your `echo`, and you have a file called `a` in the current directory.

The `[{nodelay,true}]` acts like a filename globbing pattern that will match any file whose name is any single character within the `[...]`.  In your case it matches the name of the file called `a` in the current directory.

So, quote the variable, but it would be even better to use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$SERVER_ERL_ARGS"
```

Also note that `${variable}` is exactly equivalent to `$variable` in all cases except when the expansion is part of a string where the immediately following character is valid in a variable name, like in `"${variable}x"`.

See also:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: But shouldn't the output be `a [true]`? I would suppose the `[{nodelay,true}]` to first expand to `[nodelay] [true]`, then the first pattern is replaced by `a`, but the second will either get replaced by any file called `t`, `r`, `u` or `e` or remain as `[true]`, if no file did match. Wrong?

Comment: @Philippos Brace expansion happens before variable expansion.  When the variable is expanded, the braces in its value won't be expanded. That's the difference between `echo [{nodelay,true}]` and `v='[{nodelay,true}]'; echo $v`.

Comment: With `(t)csh` and `zsh`, you also need `${var}` in things like `$var[text]` or `$var:text`.